# How do I get the text of an embedded SVG document through JS?

Tags: javascript, svg

I thought this would be really easy... what I want is the equivalent of `innerHTML`, but for SVG.  (jQuery chokes on `$("svg").html()`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [innerSVG](http://code.google.com/p/innersvg/) shim to get this functionality, it's implemented with XMLSerializer and DOMParser. Works fine in all current svg-capable browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that an SVG file is no more than XML. If that's the case something like this might work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your/svg/file.svg",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(svg) {
        var mySvgText = $(this).find("svg").text();
        // do something with svg text
    }
});​
```

This is a bit of a shot in the dark so somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "SVG defines graphics in XML format" - w3c. I would say your recollection is pretty accurate, and that is a really cool idea in my opinion for getting to the text.

Comment: @JKS: Maybe you want `$("svg").text()`, then.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing, but – like `innerHTML` – I want text and markup... `$.text` just returns text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up using:

```
var svg = $("svg:first").clone();
svg = $('<div />').append(svg);
svg = svg.html();
```